# Cannot launch openni_camera: No devices connected (ROS electric)

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, openni-kinect, linuxmint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Linux Mint 12 x64 (based on Ubuntu Oneiric) and ROS electric.

I installed the openni_kinect stack using the instructions here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-openni-kinect

hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers openni-drivers
cd openni-drivers
make
sudo make install
cd ..
hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/openni/openni_ros 
rosmake openni_kinect --rosdep-install
sudo usermod -a -G video jaustin
```

I then restarted, made sure the Kinect had external power (got a blinking green light), saw the following from lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 045e:02c2 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 014: ID 045e:02be Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 002 Device 015: ID 045e:02bf Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 413c:2105 Dell Computer Corp. Model L100 Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 045e:00cb Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse v2.0
```

But when I try to start up the openni_camera stack, it does not detect the device:

$ roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch
... logging to /home/jaustin/.ros/log/b8a3ebd8-7a9f-11e1-8f79-0090f5c64449/roslaunch-italy-18810.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is

I know there is a related question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/11447/kinect-not-detected). That question was answered, but it's from a while ago, and the answer (basically, "I re-installed ubuntu and it just worked") is not very satisfactory. So I thought it couldn't hurt to bring it up again.

Does anyone have any ideas on things I could try, or troubleshooting steps I could follow? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30889/cannot-launch-openni_camera:-no-devices-connected-(ros-electric)/) by [jessicaaustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/623/jessicaaustin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Figured it out.

I bought a ["Kinect for Windows"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006UIS53K) instead of [XBOX 360 Kinect Sensor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005UFNNWC). Apparently this new version, while it has better hardware, is [not yet supported by openni](http://groups.google.com/group/openni-dev/browse_thread/thread/648d99982443c270)

---

Originally posted by [jessicaaustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/623/jessicaaustin/) with karma: 16 on 2012-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-09-11**:
Is it supported yet? Have you tried libfreenect?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you try it out with:

**$ roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch**

**$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color**

and not with

**$ roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch**

and tell me which output you get.

BTW: Are you using the "Kinect for Winows"?

---

Originally posted by [GermanUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/2107/germanuser/) with karma: 125 on 2012-04-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get this error when I install Groovy on Ubuntu 12.10 and do the following:

1. Go to "www.openni.org/openni-sdk/openni-sdk-history-2" and download NiTE v1.5.2.21 for Linux-x64
2. Unzip it and go inside the top-level directory
3. Type: sudo ./install.sh

Before I do these 3 lines above, "roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch" works fine but after I do them I get:

No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected

Dave

---

Originally posted by [davevh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4119/davevh/) with karma: 36 on 2013-02-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jcc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1962/jcc/) on 2013-03-11**:
I'm also getting this error on fuerte and ubuntu 12.04 32bits ( i install the 32bits NITE)